# C3.js piechart tooltip not showing

Tags: javascript, c3.js

i am trying to implement pie chart in my application but piechart tooltip not showing on mouseover

below is my code

```
<link rel="icon"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.2/c3.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.2/c3.min.js" ></script>


<div id="chart"></div>

<script>
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto:'#chart',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 50]
        ],
        type: 'pie'
    },
    pie: {
        label: {
            format: function (value, ratio, id) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    },
      tooltip: {
      format: {
          title: function (d) { return 'Data ' + d; },
          value: function (value, ratio, id) {
                  return value;
          }
//            value: d3.format(',') // apply this format to both y and y2
      }
  },
});
</script>
```

i have created fiddle for the same,below is the url

https://jsfiddle.net/alokranjan39/sf9xL7m4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Including the following css seems to make the tooltip reappear, though not entirely fixed

```
g.c3-chart g.c3-event-rects rect.c3-event-rect {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Have you specified the format for the other charts? If not, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for the dirty hack (Which disables the tooltip on bar charts etc.) you can simply just rollback to the previous version v0.4.23 which was updated in May 18.

Theres not more changes and only the experimental stuff wont work, but the rest basic charts all work fine. Heres the link -> https://github.com/c3js/c3/releases/tag/v0.4.23